# cat | sort csv file by name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv, command-line-interface

i have a bunch of csv files that i want to save them in one file ordered by name

i use

```
cat *.csv | sort -t\ -k2 -n *.csv > output.csv
```

works good for a naming like a001, a002, a010. a100

but in my files the names are fup a bit so they are like a1. a2. a10. a100

and the command i wrote will arrange my things like this:

```
cn201
cn202
cn202
cn203
cn204
cn99
cn98
cn97
cn96
..
cn9
```

can anyone please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to use `-n` instead of `=n`? Also `-k' '` is easier to read than `-k\ `

Comment: Do you want to sort the contents of the files, or concatenate the files in the numerical order. So "contents of file cn5, contents of file cn20, contents of file cn100" or "sort the contents of all these files".

Comment: Do all your names start with the same prefix ? `cn` ?

Comment: i have about 4 prefixes

Comment: Floris, i have 10 csv files containing data that I want to concatenate   sorted ascending by name > cn1, cn2, cn10. cn100

Comment: sort --version-sort *.csv > clusters.csv on live server i have other version of sort so this is working in case -V option is not ! Thank you Rici !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the `-V` (version-sort) flag instead of `-n`. This is only available on GNU sort, but that's probably the one you are using.

However, it depends how you want the prefixes to be sorted.

Comment: cat *.csv | sort -t, -k=2 -V *.csv > output.csv  YOU ARE GREAT ! Thanks

Comment: @Adrian: By the way, you don't need the `cat *.csv |`. You're giving `sort` an explicit list of files (`*.csv`) so it will never read from its standard input, so the `cat` does nothing of value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the `-V` option, `sort` allows you to be more precise about what characters constitute a sort key.

```
sort -t\ -k2.3n *.csv > output.csv
```

The `.3` tells `sort` that the key to sort on starts with the 3rd character of the second field, effectively skipping the `cn` prefix. You can put the `n` directly in the field specifier, which saves you two whole characters, but more importantly for more complex sorts, allows you to treat just that key as a number, rather than applying `-n` globally (which is only an issue if you specify multiple keys with several uses of `-k`).

Answer (score 0):

The sort version on the live server is 5.97 from 2006
so few things did not work correctly.

However the code bellow is my solution

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo "This script reads all CSVs into a single file (clusters.csv) in this directory"
for filers in *.csv
do

echo "" >> clusters.csv
echo "--------------------------------" >> clusters.csv
echo $filers >> largefile.txt
echo "--------------------------------" >> clusters.csv
cat $filers >> clusters.csv

done
```

or if you want to keep it simple inside one command

```
awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv > clusers.csv
```